# SVG to CDR converter

Tags: php, svg, converters, cdr

I have an SVG file which contains rotated, semi-transparent, clipped (clip-path) elements (e.g polygons, images). This file is perfectly working in Inkscape but for further image processing I would like to use it in CorelDraw, too. But opening in CorelDraw the result is a mess (X6 actually, but earlier versions do almost the same).

Is there a method to convert SVG to native CDR or any other vector format that is CorelDraw compatible???

The SVG is on an Ubuntu LAMP server and imagemagick, inkscape, libcairo2-dev, librsvg2-bin are installed.

Comment: Do you need to convert it programmatically on the fly? Please note this one might be complicated as CDR is not an open-source but owned by CorelDraw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CorelDRAW#CDR_file_format

Answer (score 0):

To convert vectors you could use Unicovertor, which is a command-line converter supporting many formats. https://sk1project.net/uc2/

Command in terminal to convert files is

```
uniconvertor image.svg image.cdr
```

In php you could then do

```
system('uniconvertor image.svg image.cdr');
```

Please note I used this one however it can be sometimes tricky to install on ubuntu, make sure you always have the most updated version (apt-get update).

Multiple distributions are available https://sk1project.net/uc2/download/

Comment: `uniconvertor` provides wrong output when converting some SVG images. Unfortunately `Corel Draw` does not import correctly these SVG images too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inkscape` and save SVG image as PDF and import PDF in Corel Draw.

Answer (score -1):

Just a little trick.
It is not the indicated way, nor the correct way. But it works. !!

Rename the file.

> myFile.svg to myFile.cdr